# Programmatically check if Apple watch is on wrist or not?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

is it possible to check if user is wearing any wrist watch or not? So far I am unable to find any method in docs.

Comment: Possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/q/55077716/1040347

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204665 can have check over sensors if they are working if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS WatchOS5 - how to detect programmatically if Apple Watch was on the wrist (worn) at specific time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077716/ios-watchos5-how-to-detect-programmatically-if-apple-watch-was-on-the-wrist-w)

Comment: Not sure if this will suit your purpose, but `WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryState` can be checked to see if the device is on the charger.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Health kit does not provide any such information.